# Python поиск папок без файлов на диске

Tags: python

Как найти все пустые папки на диске, желательно не рекурсивно а итеративно.

Есть рекурсивная функция поиска папок, но во-первых, она рекурсивная а не итеративная, а во-вторых, она не находит пустые вложенные папки, я имею ввиду "/home/1/2/3/4/5" она покажет, только, что папка 5 пустая, но то что, перед ней все папки тоже пустые (без файлов) она не показывает.

```
empty_dir = []
def find_empty_dirs(path):
    global empty_dir
    try:
        for d in listdir(path):
            a = join(path, d)
            if isdir(a):
                find_empty_dirs(a)
                try:
                    if not listdir(a): empty_dir.append(normpath(a))
                except PermissionError:
                    pass
    except PermissionError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так нужно возвращать наверх признак, что папки внутри пустые. И проверять, что все обойденные папки пустые для этого. Примерно так (код не проверял, но суть должна быть такая):

```
def find_empty_dirs(path, empty_dir):
    try:
        is_empty = True
        for d in listdir(path):
            a = join(path, d)
            if isdir(a):
                if not find_empty_dirs(a, empty_dir):
                    is_empty = False
            else:
                is_empty = False
        empty_dir.append(normpath(path))
        return is_empty
    except PermissionError:
        return False

empty_dir = []
path = '/'
find_empty_dirs(path, empty_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

В-нулевых, никогда не используйте конструкции вида `from os import *`, `from os.path import *`! **Никогда!** Вы засоряете пространство глобальных символов множеством имён которых не знаете и которые рано или поздно пересекутся с именами ваших переменных и функций. Совершенно безобидный код вдруг поменяет своё поведение и вам будут гарантированы часы отладки со словами "я же тут написал как надо, почему оно не вызывается?"

Во-первых, никаких собираний результатов в список. Обход каталогов длительная операция, выдавать данные наверх нужно как только они стали доступны. Так что нужно делать генератор, который будет выдавать наверх каталог и флажок `(не)пустой`. Генератор пока будет рекурсивный - так проще. Если при обработке каталога встретился `не каталог`, то текущий каталог будет отправлен как не пустой. То же самое будет если нашёлся не пустой подкаталог.

Во-вторых, обработку ошибок надо локализовать. Если закрывать блоками `try` большие куски кода вы потеряете часть информации. Например, при обработке каталога в середине проверка подкаталога ошиблась. Тогда весь хвост каталога не будет обработан.

Рекурсивная программа:

```
import os
import sys


def listdir(path):
    try:
        yield from os.listdir(path)
    except PermissionError:
        print(f'find-empty-dirs: ‘{path}’: Permission denied', file=sys.stderr)


def isdir(path):
    try:
        return os.path.isdir(path)
    except PermissionError:
        print(f'find-empty-dirs: ‘{path}’: Permission denied', file=sys.stderr)
        return False


def dirs(path):
    empty = True
    for name in listdir(path):
        entry = os.path.join(path, name)
        if isdir(entry):
            for e, p in dirs(entry):
                if e:
                    yield e, p
                else:
                    empty = False
        else:
            empty = False
    yield empty, path


def empty_dirs(path):
    for e, p in dirs(path):
        if e:
            yield p


def main():
    for path in sys.argv[1:]:
        for d in empty_dirs(path):
            print(d)


main()
```

Нерекурсивная версия рекурсивного генератор потребует явного стека, который хранит тройки [`путь`, `(не)пусто`, `итератор`]. Итератор двигается по каталогу с помощью вызова `next(итератор, None)`. Признаки не пустоты обновляются при движении по каталогам и передаются наверх когда каталог кончился. Из рекурсивной программы нужно убрать функции `dirs`, `empty_dirs` и добавить эту:

```
def empty_dirs(root):
    stack = [[root, True, listdir(root)]]

    while stack:
        path, empty, it = stack[-1]
        name = next(it, None)
        if name is None:
            stack.pop()
            if empty:
                yield path
            else:
                if stack:
                    stack[-1][1] = False
        else:
            entry = os.path.join(path, name)
            if isdir(entry):
                stack.append([entry, True, listdir(entry)])
            else:
                stack[-1][1] = False
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение и приведенный код, столкнулся с такой проблемой:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Жаловался на:
in empty_dirs name = next(it, None)
in listdir  yield from listdir(path)

Хотя очень странно, я проверил на пустой папке с 3 вложенными папками...
взял empty_dirs из второго блока, не рекурсивного.

Comment: @AlgiZ, никогда не используйте конструкцию `from os.path import *`, `from os import *`, `from <имя любого модуля> import *`. Это приводит к смешению локальных и системных символов, которую вы сейчас и пытаетесь расхлебать.

Comment: Например: что сейчас делает символ `listdir`? Это функция определённая в вашем коде? Или она импортирована из `os.path`? Вы смешали два определения и, конечно, получили рекурсию.

Comment: да не заметил пересечений названий функций. Все работает, Спасибо большое еще раз!